# error : mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in(couldnt solve issue using search in forum)

Tags: mysql

I'm a php and mysql newbie, and am trying to get data from a table in database, but am getting this error:
    `warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ali-cms`

```
this is my index.php:
<?php require_once("config.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
<div class="middle">
  <?php require_once("right_side.php"); ?>
</div>
<div class="middle"> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="context">
      <?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'tbl_post' ORDER BY 'id' DESC";
$res = mysql_query($query,$con);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo $rows['id'].'<br>';
    }
?>
      <div class="newstitle">
        <li><a href="">عنوان یک</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>لورم ایپسوم یا طرح‌نما (به انگلیسی: Lorem ipsum) به متنی آزمایشی و بی‌معنی در صنعت چاپ، صفحه‌آرایی و طراحی گرافیک گفته می‌شود. طراح گرافیک از این متن به عنوان عنصری از ترکیب بندی برای پر کردن صفحه و ارایه اولیه شکل ظاهری و کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می نماید، تا از نظر گرافیکی نشانگر چگونگی نوع و اندازه فونت و ظاهر متن باشد. معمولا طراحان گرافیک </p>
      </div>
      <div class="readmore">
        <form>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="دنباله نوشته">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

This is my config.php file:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ali_db";


$con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die('connection error');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ('Database Error !');
mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

defined('ADDR') or define('ADDR','http://localhost/ali-cms/');
?>
```

Comment: first of all, you are using `mysql` extension which is deprecated and it's better to choose between `mysqli` and `pdo`. second, please be more specific about which line generate the error. third, if you have an error in you `query`, `mysql_query` will return false and that's your case. so please recheck your query. you are using _single quote_ instead of `Backtick` which is left side of key 1 on your keyboard. also check table name and field name to see if they are correct.

Comment: thanks a million,problem solved,my mistake was using ' instead of `